# Android kotlin coroutine: await might silently drop exceptions

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

While reading https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines I stumbled upon the following warning:

> Warning: launch and async handle exceptions differently. Since async expects an eventual call to await at some point, it holds exceptions and rethrows them as part of the await call. **This means if you use await to start a new coroutine from a regular function, you might silently drop an exception.** These dropped exceptions won't appear in your crash metrics or be noted in logcat.

However I'm not able to find any example of this silent-dropping behavior while browsing https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html or any other resources returned by https://www.google.com/search?q=kotlin+await+exception+handling - on the contrary, all resources indicate that exception thrown in an async/await block will cause a failure in the whole coroutine scope which is correct and expected.

I'm afraid I'm missing something here, can you provide an example where this silent exception dropping occurs which cannot be noted in logcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The passage you quote from Kotlin documentation is outdated. It used to be true in the experimental phase, and you really could get swallow exceptions if you weren't very pedantic.

The release version of coroutines acquired an additional key component: *structured concurrency*. When following the simple guidelines not to use `GlobalScope` and similar, your code will automatically be organized such that each coroutine has a parent and there's a well-defined scope within which all coroutines must complete either normally or abruptly, and the owner of that scope can await its completion, getting the exception that caused the abnormal completion.

Within this new discipline, `launch` and `async` are on the same footing. If an exception thrown inside one of them escapes its top-level block, it goes on to cancel the coroutine, notify the parent of this, and then the parent may opt to cancel all the other children so that the whole scope ends prematurely.

Note that getting an exception from the `await` call is an entirely different mechanism. The thing you `await` on is not the `async` block itself, but a standalone object of type `Deferred`, which is identical to Java's `Future` except that `await` suspends instead of blocks. The `async` block, upon completion, always does the same: it completes the `Deferred` with either the return value or the exception. You may retrieve that result from anywhere you pass the `Deferred`, it's completely decoupled from the destiny of the `async` coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found an example which is in line with Marko's answer concerning structured concurrency. Code snippet below presents the silent exception dropping usecase.

This example comes from https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-ii-getting-started-3bff117176dd

```
val unrelatedScope = MainScope()

// example of a lost error
suspend fun lostError() {
    // async without structured concurrency
    unrelatedScope.async {
        throw InAsyncNoOneCanHearYou("except")
    }
}
```

> Note this code is declaring an unrelated coroutine scope that will launch a new coroutine without structured concurrency. [...]
>   The error is lost in this code because async assumes that you will eventually call await where it will rethrow the exception. However, if you never do call await, the exception will be stored forever waiting patiently to be raised.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions from `launch` are thrown "instantly" into exception handler, while those from `async` will be thrown the moment you call `await`.

Sample code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking{
    println("main start")
    val l = GlobalScope.launch{ justThrow("launch") }
    val a = GlobalScope.async { justThrow("async") }
    delay(500)
    // a.await()
    println("main finished")
}

suspend fun justThrow(who : String){
    println("starting $who")
    delay(100)
    throw Exception("Test exception from $who")
}
```

Output:

```
main start
starting launch
starting async
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#2" java.lang.Exception: Test exception from launch
    at FileKt.justThrow(File.kt:15)
    (... entire stack here )
main finished
```

You can see `launch` throwing exception in worker thread but there's nothing from `async`, even though it executed the same function that must fail.

For next run modify the code by removing the `launch` for clarity and uncommenting `a.await()`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking{
    println("main start")
    val a = GlobalScope.async { justThrow("async") }
    delay(500)
    a.await()
    println("main finished")
}
```

Output:

```
main start
starting async
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Test exception from async
 at FileKt.justThrow (File.kt:15)
 (... entire stack here )
```

Exception is held instead of crashing in worker thread and is instead re-thrown the moment `await()` is called which causes the app to crash. You can notice it happened on `main` thread and there was no "main finished" print because of that.

Comment: What you presented is an expected behavior that is also obvious to me. I'll stick with @Marko Topolnik answer and assume that the documentation is outdated and this silent exception dropping behavior is not possible in current coroutines implementation.